# Segmentation Fault and other issues after switching to XFCE

Tags: 11.10, xfce, segmentation-fault

After switching to XFCE.. Many apps are segfaulting including VirtualBox and MonkeyStudio.
Apps like Minitube give this warning

> `Creating accessible with different object than the original interface!`

Is there any fix?

Comment: Did you perform the switch from ubuntu or kubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu to xfce..

Comment: @AmithKK - any other trace?  e.g. this bug report has the same text reported for clementine - the package qt-at-spi needed to be removed...

Comment: @fossfreedom Indeed, that fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

There is a [bug-report](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=2327) that included the error message you reported - it was logged against this [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt-at-spi/+bug/875661)

Given that Minitube and Clementine are both QT multimedia apps, the resolution below would be a good candidate to try.

The resolution was to remove the package `qt-at-spi`

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi
```